# to_html return UnicodeEncodeError when include Chinese characters

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to translate aaa.xls (a file including Chinese characters) to bbb.html, but `to_html` reports `UnicodeEncodeError`. How can I fix it?

**code:**

```
/#coding: utf-8
import pandas  

def xls2html(): 
    df = pandas.read_excel('aaa.xls')   
    df.to_html('bbb.html',bold_rows=False)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xls2html()
```

**error:**

```
df.to_html('aa2.html',bold_rows=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1608, in to_html
    formatter.to_html(classes=classes, notebook=notebook, border=border)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 703, in to_html
    html_renderer.write_result(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 1035, in write_result
    _put_lines(buf, self.elements)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 2646, in _put_lines
    buf.write('\n'.join(lines))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 109-111: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Try to read your Excel file in UTF-8: `df = pandas.read_excel('aaa.xls', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

thank you all

I solved this issue as below:

```
# coding: utf-8
import pandas  
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')


def xls2html(): 
    df = pandas.read_excel('aaa.xls',encoding='gbk')    

    df.to_html('bbb.html',bold_rows=False)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xls2html()
```